# Init hook function to call other hook in function.php

Tags: init

I am trying to add a function in the `init` hook that will call another hook like this :

```
add_action( 'init', 'loadAfterUserRegistrationHook' );
    function loadAfterUserRegistrationHook(){
    add_action( 'user_meta_after_user_register', 'createNewPost' );  
}    

function createNewPost( $response ){
global $userMeta;

$userID = $response->ID;
$user = new WP_User( $userID );

$role = $userMeta->getUserRole();

if( $role = 'artiste' ){ 

    $newPost = array(
      'post_title'    => $user->nickname, 
      'post_content'  => $user->description,
      'post_status'   => 'pending',
      'post_author'   => $userID,
      'post_type'     => 'cpt_artists'
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $newPost );
    error_log('Post ID : '.$post_id);

    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array('dj'), 'artist-category');

   }
 }
```

Why is the function `createNewPost` is not being executed?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps running it on the `user_register` hook?

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'loadAfterUserRegistrationHook' );
    function loadAfterUserRegistrationHook(){
    add_action( 'user_meta_after_user_register', 'createNewPost' );  
}
```

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form

Comment: No because i need to set custom taxonomy and they are not loaded if i don't run it on the init hook.

Comment: I believe your custom taxonomy is available at this point. Have you tried running it yet?

Comment: Yes i have tried, createNewPost function is lauched but my term is not set :(.

Comment: Godwinh please be my savior lol

Comment: The one way i find to set terms is `add_action( 'init', 'testFunction' );
    function testFunction(){
    wp_set_object_terms( 120, array('dj'), 'artist-category');  
}` But i can't have the id of the post